# Automatically replace first line in each file

Tags: php, css, minify

I have a couple of minified files (CSS and JS) and I want to automatically replace the first line of each one (the first line of each file is something like `Minified @ 2017-03-21`) when I re-minify those files.

I'm currently adding that info in this way, but I accept suggestions:

```
<?php
$file = "test.css";
$add_info = "/* --- Minified today --- */ \n";
$add_info .= file_get_contents($file);
file_put_contents($file, $add_info);
?>
```

So my file ends like this:

```
/* --- Minified today --- */
body{margin:0}; /* etc */
```

And obviously after a couple repeats ends like this:

```
/* --- Minified today --- */
/* --- Minified today --- */
/* --- Minified today --- */
/* --- Minified today --- */
body{margin:0}; /* etc */
```

which isn't useful at all.

So, how can I do that (without killing performance)? That action will be performed just 1 o 2 times per week (as most), and the files are ~30KB after minify.

Note: I'm using PHP 5.5 and Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the file into an array with `file()` and replace the first line.  Then `file_put_contents()` will implode the array for you:

```
$file = "test.css";
$lines = file($file);
$add_info = "/* --- Minified today --- */ \n";
$lines[0] = $add_info;
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
```

If they may not have that as a first line then check and either replace it or insert it:

```
if(strpos($lines[0], '/* --- Minified') !== false) {
    $lines[0] = $add_info;
} else {
    array_unshift($lines, $add_info);
}
```

Comment: For what you stated, you won't even notice.  Probably no different than what you are doing now. The only difference is an array instead of a string.

Comment: When may the difference be noticed? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Very large files that are opened Very frequently.

Comment: Right, I get it. Now I used this method but some files doesn't have the first line previously, so how can I add it? Some files are minified into 1 line, so the first line is _all_ the code.

Comment: Edited with a check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138673/discussion-between-jimmy-adaro-and-abracadaver).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was large files.  This is a solution I use.  I currently echos but you could always save to a file.

```
$fh = fopen($local_file, 'rb');
echo "add\tfirst\tline\n";  // add your new first line.
fgets($fh); // moves the file pointer to the next line.
echo stream_get_contents($fh); // flushes the remaining file.
fclose($fh);
```